# How to setup celery with non standard django project?

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery

Our django project structure is something like that:

```
project
  project
    apps (folder with django apps)
      consumer
      provider
        notifications
          tasks.py (celery tasks)
    locale
    static
    site (urls and settings files, we have different settings for, site, widget, api)
      api
      web
      widget
      provider (this one is going to use celery)
        settings
          dev.py
          settings.py
        urls 
          urls.py
        __init__.py
    manage.py
```

I tried to put celery.py in site/provider folder but than I have problem running celery worker. I am not sure from which folder run worker.

Celery has to use settings for provider and search for task in apps folder.

Comment: I have my celery.py in my settings directory, the same as settings.py.

"I have problem" doesn't give enough detail to help further.

Comment: @Rachel Celery.py is in provider folder I have also modify __init__.py to run celery app. When I start django server celery app, start properly. Than I start worker from site folder with command "celery -A provider worker -l info". I got error "no module found". I tried also to go to provider folder and start celery worker (without -A flag). Celery worker start but tasks aren't loaded so than I got error about not founding right task.